# How to troubleshoot IPMI in MAAS? What logs to look at?

Tags: maas

I'm looking for information/tips to troubleshoot IPMI in MAAS 1.6.  Are there any log locations to examine, debug output etc.  From the MAAS region/cluster host I can use ipmitool successfully.  So tips on troubleshooting this are appreciated and/or how IPMI commands might be specifically configured for certain node hardware.

Answer (score 4):

The place to look for this kind of information is `/var/log/maas/celery.log`. Whenever a node is powered on by MAAS it should contain an entry such as:

```
[2014-05-28 10:10:54,226: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: provisioningserver.tasks.power_on[65b69047-46ca-4164-ad32-cb3362e79de9]
[2014-05-28 10:10:54,447: INFO/MainProcess] Task provisioningserver.tasks.power_on[65b69047-46ca-4164-ad32-cb3362e79de9] succeeded in 0.220459055s: None
```

And if the task fails, then it should show up some traceback along with the failure.